# How to gray out items in Source Control Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

I accidentally hit "Get Latest Version" on item in TFS with which I'm not currently working on. This made name of the item visible in black in Source Control Explorer, which is misleading to me since I'm used to identify objects which I'm working on visually. How can I reverse this operation?

Answer (score 1):

To make the item in Source Control Explorer gray out again. You could try below workaround, get specific changeset 1.

1. Open team explorer
2. Click Source Control
3. Right click on you file/folder
4. Select **Advanced** Click on Get specific Version
5. Choose Changeset Type and enter 1

[image]

The item in Source Control Explorer will gray out again. This is due to:

> Changeset 1 is a special changeset on your Team Foundation Server
>   instance. It was created as part of the setup routine and only
>   contains one thing - the root node ($/) in your source control tree.
>   If you do a get for Changeset 1 on any actual files then they will not
>   exist at that point in time on the system so will be deleted locally
>   and the server will know this.

***Note:*** This will change the status of your files to "Not downloaded" and will **remove the local copy of the file**. It will only remove files that were put there by TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TFVC, you can also try cloaking the folders that you don't need. This will "remove" the any unchanged files locally and exclude the folders when you get latest in future.

In the Source Control Explorer, right click on the folders that you want to exclude and go to "advanced" then select "cloak".
[image: Cloak in Source Control Explorer]

To start using the files locally, you can go to the same place and select "uncloak".